# How can i show a sweetalert message before form submit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I'm having trouble with sweetalert, I want it to pop up a message in sweetalert telling the user that the vehicle was inserted, and when he clicks on the "Ok" button, it should make the submission of the form.
I have this code, and it's not working for me, can anyone help ?

```js
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("form").submit(function (event) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var form = $(this);
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Registado',
                text: 'O seu veiculo foi registado!'
            }, function () {
                $(this).trigger('sumbit');
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Form is going through, but no sweetalert message is shown.

Edit1: Its now showing the sweetalert, but the submission is not going. This code works but its with JS alert -

```js
$("form").submit(function(){
  alert("Submitted");
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Couple of things that I have immediately noticed:

- You are passing in `event`, but trying to call `e.preventDafault()`.
- `$(this).trigger('sumbit');` typo.

Updated those issue in the below snippet.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var shownPopup = false;
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        if (shownPopup === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            shownPopup = true;
            var form = $(this);
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Registado',
                text: 'O seu veiculo foi registado!'
            }, function () {
                form.trigger('submit');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Here is a solution using promises, as seen implemented in the https://sweetalert2.github.io/ docs:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    var shownPopup = false;
    $("form").submit(function (event) {
        if (shownPopup === false) {
            event.preventDefault();
            shownPopup = true;
            var form = $(this);
            Swal.fire({
                icon: 'success',
                title: 'Registado',
                text: 'O seu veiculo foi registado!'
            }).then(function() {
                form.trigger('submit');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the sweetalert it now appearing, but the form is not being submitted now.

Comment: @DiogoNeves are you sure you are using the sweetalert correctly? From what I read at their website you have to use .then() to continue (or capture).

Comment: I don't know sweetalert at all. But I have edited my answer above to cater for needed form submission.

Comment: @NawedKhan from what i have searched here in stackoverflow, almost everyone uses it like this...

Comment: @AdrianRoworth i think it did, thanks. Now i have other issue thats related with how im building the website, if i want to use sweetalert, ill have to make the POST thats being used in PHP, and convert all my code ajax, so i can make the insertions into the DB, ill have to call it, with sweetalert and migrate to ajax, or without sweetalert but with PHP.

Comment: If you are having additional issues still. Try submitting another question about that if you haven't already

Answer (score 0):

It seems your preventDefault is not working because you have e.preventDefault(); instead of event.preventDefault();
knowing that your function takes "event" rather than "e" as argument.